# How to generate a dataframe from groupby() outputs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe with information from weather stations:

```
      df_Station_Weather = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['102', '102', '102',
                                                '558', '115', '115'], 
                                         'Code_Instrument': ['SEN_wider1898', 'SEN_rain1015', 
                                                             'SEN_UV', 'SEN_wider1898',
                                                             'SEN_wider1898', 'SEN_rain1015'],
                                         'Quantity': [6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9]})

      print(df_Station_Weather)

      ID    Code_Instrument Quantity
     102    SEN_wider1898      6
     102    SEN_rain1015       2
     102    SEN_UV             2
     558    SEN_wider1898      2
     115    SEN_wider1898      1
     115    SEN_rain1015       9
```

I would like to identify two pieces of information: the first information would be the total amount of the same equipment and the second information would be the number of stations that have this type of instrument.

To identify the total sum of instruments I did the following:

```
      Total_Quantity = df_Station_Weather.groupby(['Code_Instrument'])['Quantity'].sum()
```

The output is felt as desired:

```
       Code_Instrument
            SEN_UV            2
            SEN_rain1015     11
            SEN_wider1898     9
```

To identify the number of stations that have this type of equipment I used:

```
      Total_Station_Quantity = df_Station_Weather.groupby(['Code_Instrument'])['ID'].count()
```

The output is felt as desired:

```
       Code_Instrument
             SEN_UV           1
             SEN_rain1015     2
             SEN_wider1898    3
```

My question is how to transform these outputs into a dataframe, that is, how do I get the return of the groupby() function to generate a dataframe?
My desired output would be:

```
        Code_Instrument     Sum_Instrument     Station_Weather_Quantity
        SEN_wider1898             9                 3      
        SEN_rain1015              11                2
        SEN_UV                    2                 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do with `agg`

```
yourdf=df_Station_Weather.groupby('Code_Instrument').agg(Station_Weather_Quantity=('ID','count'),
                                                  Sum_Instrument=('Quantity','sum')).reset_index()
Out[175]: 
  Code_Instrument  Station_Weather_Quantity  Sum_Instrument
0          SEN_UV                         1               2
1    SEN_rain1015                         2              11
2   SEN_wider1898                         3               9
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one-line like so:

```
df = pd.concat([Total_Quantity, Total_Station_Quantity], axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)
#  Code_Instrument  Quantity  ID
#0          SEN_UV         2   1
#1    SEN_rain1015        11   2
#2   SEN_wider1898         9   3
```